# Regex: Illegal hexadecimal escape sequence

Tags: java, regex, regular-language

I am new to Regex..I wrote the following regex to check phone numbers in javascript: `^[0-9\+\-\s\(\)\[\]\x]*$`

Now, I try to the same thing in java using the following code:

```
public class testRegex {

    public static void main(String[] args){

    String regex="^[0-9\\+\\-\\s\\(\\)\\[\\]\\x]*$";

    String phone="98650056";

    System.out.println(phone.matches(regex));

}
```

However, I always get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: 
    Illegal hexadecimal escape sequence near index 21^[0-9\+\-\s\\(\\)\\[\\]\x]*$
```

Please advise.

Comment: Isn't `\x` is the start of a hexadecimal escape sequence? For example, \x0FF0. Take a look at javascript's regex to see what you want instead of `\x`

Comment: here is the exact javascript: var contactNumberRegExp = /^[0-9\+\-\s\\(\\)\\[\\]\x]*$/;

Comment: `\x` is the start of a byte `\x0F` or so. In java rare, because java uses unicode, `\u000F` would be more regular. Does the regex mean that a character 'x' is allowed? Maybe originally there was `\x09` aka tab. Leave `\x` out.

Comment: Your regex matches `++++++++------()()()()()()()`, not sure it's a valid phone number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are trying to match what I assume is `x` (as in a phone extension), it needs to be escaped with four backslashes, or not escaped at all; otherwise `\x` is interpreted as a hexidecimal escape code. Because `\x` is interpreted as a hex code without the two to four additional required chars it's an error.

```
     [\\x] \x{nn} or {nnnn} (hex code nn to nnnn)
   [\\\\x] x (escaped)
       [x] x
```

So the pattern becomes:

```
String regex="^[-0-9+()\\s\\[\\]x]*$";
```

Escaped Alternatives:

```
String regex="^[0-9\\+\\-\\s\\(\\)\\[\\]x]*$";
String regex="^[0-9\\+\\-\\s\\(\\)\\[\\]\\\\x]*$";
```

Comment: +1 but there're no needs to escape `+()` and `-` when in first or last position.

Answer (score 0):

You have waaaay too many back slashes!

Firstly, to code a literal backslash in java, you must write *two* of them.

Secondly, most characters lose their special regex meaning when in a character class.

Thirdly, `\x` introduces a hex literal - you don't want that.

Write your regex like this:

```
String regex="^[0-9+\\s()\\[\\]x-]*$";
```

Note how you don't need to escape the hyphen in a character class when it appears first or last.